# Some optimisations?

Tags: html, css

it's been two weeks since I started learning web development and am currently practicing designing a friend contact page. The problem is, I find my code very poorly optimized and can't do what I want. Do you have any suggestions on what changes I could make to my code?

For the HTML part, I feel like I put a little too much:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.jpeg">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
        <div class="sociall">
            <ul id="ul_social">
                <a href="link" target="_blank"><div class="sbutton"><li id="li_insta">Instagram</li></div></a>
                <a href="link" target="_blank"><div class="sbutton"><li id="li_snap">Snapchat</li></div></a>
                <a href="link" target="_blank"><div class="sbutton"><li id="li_tiktok">Tiktok</li></div></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the CSS part, I'm not sure, I'm kinda lost. I can't seem to figure out if everything is properly organized and whether or not it's optimizing.:

````
/* Général */

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

/* Privé */

.background{
    background-image: url('img/background.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    filter: blur(1px);

}

.logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    user-select: none;
}

.logo img{
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

.social{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -1%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    user-select: none;
}

.sociall{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sbutton:hover{
    background-color: rgba(7, 75, 150, 0.50);
}

.sbutton{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 4px;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

#li_insta{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-image: url("img/instagram.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 10px 75px 0 75px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

#li_snap{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-image: url("img/snapchat.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 10px 75px 0 75px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

#li_tiktok{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-image: url("img/tiktok.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 10px 75px 0 75px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}```

Thank you in advance for your help.
````

Comment: What do you mean by poorly optimized? And what are some things you want it to do that you feel like it can't?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you seem to arbitrarily choose between class and id selectors. It's advisable to use class selectors for everything, except when dealing with logic. Better yet, you could try following a CSS design pattern (like BEM).

Moreover, you unnecessarily repeat a lot of CSS properties. For example, you could easily have created a single "li_item" class containing the unchanged properties then made the respective classes changing only the needed properties:

```css
.li_item {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 10px 75px 0 75px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.li_item--snap {
    background-image: url("img/snapchat.png");
}

.li_item--tictac {
    background-image: url("img/tictac.png");
}
```

On HTML:

```html
<li class="li_item li_item--snap">Snapchat</li>
<li class="li_item li_item--tictac">TikTok</li>
```